# How to run the script in robotframework in a automated way based on json Condition

Tags: python, robotframework

Either 1 or 2 Json files will be generated in a folder when we run the python script,
so if 1 json file is generated , i need to run   robot --loglevel TRACE Timeautomation.robot
and if 2 json files are generated, I need to run robot --loglevel TRACE Timeautomation1.robot

So how do i do this in robotframework in a automated way to run the scripts based on json Condition generated in a folder
Please help me

Comment: This is not exactly a Robot Framework question. I would solve this using shell scripts. It would look like this: 
1) run script that generates json files
2) if there is only one file, run Timeautomation.robot
3) if there are two files, run Timeautomation1.robot

Comment: @Nikhil  Also what pekka said, since you didnt even hint what operating system you are running this on, impossible to give you any details..